# Nested if Statement Problems - Comparison Operator

Tags: c++, dev-c++

(Using dev c++) As I'm quite new to c++ I decided to make a basic text RPG game. I've debugged the program many times and it comes up with nothing whatsoever. Every time I test the program and, lets say I want to attack the traveler, it prints TEST(Which I put there for the time being until I could fix the the problem). If I switch the if(attack=="talk"||"Talk") with if(attack=="attack"||"Attack"), then I want to talk with the traveler it prints "You rush forward and murder the traveler to find he was un-armed!" All help will be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    string dir, attack, trade;
    string inventory[] = {"Food", "Sword", "Armor"};
    cout << "Do you go left, right or forward?" << endl;
    cin >> dir;
    if(dir=="left"||"Left") {
        cout << "You decide to go left" << endl;
        cout << "On the way you meet a traveller, do you attack or talk?" << endl;
        cin >> attack;
       if(attack=="talk"||"Talk") {
             cout << "TEST" << endl;
             }
       else if(attack=="attack"||"Attack") {
             cout << "You rush forward and murder the traveller to find he was un-armed!\a" << endl;
             }
       else  {
             cout << "test" << endl;
             }

     }
    else if(dir=="Right"||"Right") {
        cout << "You decide to go right" << endl;
        }
    else {
         cout << "You decide to go forward" << endl;
         }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change it to `dir=="left"||dir=="Left"`. Otherwise it'll be always `true`.

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ transform string".  If you convert the string to all uppercase or all lowercase before comparing, you will only need to make one comparison.

Comment: BTW, you have a typo in your check for the "right" direction; both comparison texts are the same.

Comment: You have a flaw in  you logic.  If I enter "burrito" to your prompt, it will report that I want to go forward, which is wrong.  Now is a good time to start considering how to handle invalid input.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `||` operator as, for example, `if(dir=="Right"||"Right")`

This is the wrong usage as this evaluates the second part `"Right"` as `true` always. Change **ALL** your comparisons to this routine:

`if(dir=="Right"|| dir=="Right")`

However, here, both statements are the same since "Right" is the same as "Right". Check your logic, did you mean `dir == "Right" || dir == "right"`?

Here is a clean copy of your code after fixing the issues I mentioned:

```
int main() 
{
    string dir, attack, trade;
    string inventory[] = { "Food", "Sword", "Armor" };

    cout << "Do you go left, right or forward?" << endl;
    cin >> dir;

    if (dir == "left" || dir == "Left")
    {
        cout << "You decide to go left" << endl;
        cout << "On the way you meet a traveller, do you attack or talk?" << endl;
        cin >> attack;

        if (attack == "talk" || attack == "Talk")
            cout << "TEST" << endl;
        else if (attack == "attack" || attack == "Attack") 
                    cout << "You rush forward and murder the traveller to find he was un-armed!\a" << endl;
                else 
                    cout << "test" << endl;
    }
    else if (dir == "Right" || dir == "right") 
                cout << "You decide to go right" << endl;
            else 
                cout << "You decide to go forward" << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cin >> attack;
       if(attack=="talk"||"Talk") {
             cout << "TEST" << endl;
             }
       else if(attack=="attack"||"Attack") {
             cout << "You rush forward and murder the traveller to find he was un-armed!\a" << endl;
             }
       else  {
             cout << "test" << endl;
             }` is the main problem, do you reckon you could help?

Comment: @BramwellSimpson I think you need to read my answer again. Look at your `if` statements: `if(attack=="talk"||"Talk")` .. This is wrong

Comment: The OP can remove this issue by *transforming* the text to all lowercase or all uppercase before making the comparison.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Very useful comment. Thank you

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks for the tip, doing it now.

Answer (score 1):

Just an explanation in addition to songyuanyao's/FirstStep's answer:

```cpp
if(dir == "left" || "Left")
```

is equivalent to

```cpp
if((dir == "left") || ("Left"))
```

which is equivalent again to

```cpp
if((dir == "left") || ("Left" != 0))
```

And as the string literal "Left" has an address in memory unequal to 0...

Side note: "Left" isn't even converted to std::string for this.